# how to make JDA take user messages and not the bot

Tags: java, discord-jda

A user sends a message, and the bot replies, and in another discord channel, there are buttons that can delete the message, but when you click on the delete message button, the bot's message is deleted and not the user's, how do I fix it?.

```
public void onButtonInteraction(ButtonInteractionEvent event) {
    if(event.getComponentId().equals("acc")) {
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(messageID).queue();
        event.getChannel()
                .sendMessage(event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("1195039391563907082").getLatestMessageId()).queue();
        event.deferEdit().queue();
    }
}
```

at first I tried to check if it was a bot or not, but then I thought about it

Comment: What did you think about? your question is incomplete and really hard to understand

Comment: Have you tried [Modals](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#modals)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand English, I use a translator.

The way it works for me is that the user wrote a message, and the bot replied, and in another discord channel, there are buttons that can delete the message, but when you click on the delete message button, the bot's message is deleted and not the user's, how do I fix it?

Comment: Provide the code you used, there isn't enough code.

Comment: `    public void onButtonInteraction(ButtonInteractionEvent event) {
        if (event.getComponentId().equals("acc")) {


            //event.getChannel().sendMessage(messageID).queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("1195039391563907082").getLatestMessageId()).queue();
            event.deferEdit().queue();
        }`

Comment: please include the code where you create this button, and add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you get the last message of the channel, which was sent by the bot.

A simpler solution would be to store the message ID, and use that ID to delete the message

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getJumpUrl()).addActionRow(Button.danger("delete"+event.getMessageId(), "Delete Message")).queue();
}
    
@Override
public void onButtonInteraction(ButtonInteractionEvent event) {
        
    if(event.getId().contains("delete")) { 
        String id;
        id = event.getId().replace("delete", "");
            
        event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("1195039391563907082").deleteMessageById(id).queue();
    }
}
```

Make sure you change this based on your requirement.

Comment: event.getComponentId().contains("delete") Does not find the button

Comment: Sorry i meant to use `getId()`

Comment: if(event.getComponentId().indexOf("acc") != -1) {
            String id;
            id = event.getComponentId().replace("acc", "");
            System.out.println(id);

            event.getJDA().getTextChannelById("1096216076863414306").deleteMessageById(id).queue();
            event.deferEdit().queue();
        } // I refactored your code a bit, I figured out how it works thanks